# Laravel + SQS Messages are processed every second and not removed from queue

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-sqs

I have set up SQS with my Laravel 5 (Spark) app and it is running great (ish)

I have an event that is generated each time a new account is created. This event triggers a mail class which implements ShoudlQueue.

When running:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

The same messages in SQS are shown as processing every second. Is there something I need to do on so that my events mark the queue messages as complete and remove them from the SQS queue?

In my store user function:

```
event(new UserCreated($user));
```

This then fires the following event:

```
class UserCreated
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

I then have an event subscriber set up:

```
class UserEventSubscriber
{

    public function onUserCreated($event)
    {
        Mail::to($event->user)->queue(new UserCreated($event->user)); 
    }

    public function subscribe($events)
    {
        $events->listen(
            'App\Events\User\UserCreated',
            'App\Listeners\UserEventSubscriber@onUserCreated'
        );
    }
}
```

And finally the mail class:

```
namespace App\Mail;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class UserCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.users.test');
    }
}
```

Comment: Code please...?

Comment: @JonStirling Thats normally pretty useful! Updated.

Comment: please check if there's error on the mailing side.

Answer (score 0):

I've had better luck with...

`php artisan queue:work --daemon`

...when working with Laravel's queues and SQS particularly.

Also, your `UserCreated` class is missing `implements ShouldQueue`.

I'm not sure if you just left it out of your snippet. But you would want to make sure your `UserEventSubscriber` is registered in your `EventServiceProvider` class as well.